# Powershell export-csv .... adding row number to output just can't be that complicated

Tags: powershell, row, export-csv

Folks,

In the past I've struggled for hours trying to do something in Powershell and then have someone here answer with the simplest one line answer.  I'm hoping for the same now after spending hours on this.

I want to import a csv file and export the data with an added column for row number.

Input Data

```
"Employee","State"
"Sally","ME"
"Bob","FL"
"Pete","ID"
"Martha","CA"
```

Desired Output

```
"Employee","State","FileName","Emp#"
"Sally","ME","test","1"
"Bob","FL","test","2"
"Pete","ID","test","3"
"Martha","CA","test","4"
```

One thing I've tried out of my dozens of attempts:

```
$filePath = "$dataDir\test.csv"
$out = "$dataDir\test_out.csv" 

$Fname = (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[0];

$data2 = Import-Csv $filePath 
foreach ($x in $data2) 
            {$count=$count++
             $data2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FileName -Value $Fname -Force
             $data2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Emp# -Value $count -Force
            }
$data2 | export-csv $out -NoTypeInformation
```

All this does is put a 0 in the Emp# column.  Help please?

Comment: This should work : $x | Add-Member -NotePropertyName FileName -NotePropertyValue $Fname;
 $x | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Emp# -NotePropertyValue $count

Comment: you're adding to `$data2` (the collection being enumerated) instead of to `$x` (the item in the collection)

Comment: perhaps I don't understand where to place your code but it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: You should initialize $count to zero before entering the loop.

Comment: You should leave out the $count = in front of the $count++.  ++ stores the incremented value back in the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreating the objects with `Select-Object` might just be easier than attaching new properties:

```bash
$filePath = Join-Path $dataDir -ChildPath 'test.csv'
$fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($filePath)
$out = Join-Path $dataDir -ChildPath 'test_out.csv'
$i = @{ Counter = 0 }

Import-Csv $filePath |
    Select-Object *, @{ N='FileName'; E={ $fileName }}, @{ N='Emp#'; E={ (++$i.Counter) }} |
    Export-Csv $out -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.  Brilliant solution in my eyes.

Comment: @ljg glad it was helpful

Comment: @ljg do you want me to add how it would be done with `Add-Member` ? I wouldn't recommend that solution tho, it is very inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Agree, it *shouldn't* be that complicated...
Anyways, using this [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)) [which is *not* standard PowerShell equipment!](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14994). You might use this semantic sugar:

```
Import-Csv $filePath |Join (,'Test' * 4) |Join (1..4) -Name FileName, Empl#

Employee State FileName Empl#
-------- ----- -------- -----
Sally    ME    Test         1
Bob      FL    Test         2
Pete     ID    Test         3
Martha   CA    Test         4
```

**Explanation**
The syntax above takes advantage of the following `Join-Object` features:

- When the `-on` parameter is omitted, the objects are joined side-by-side.
- An array of scalars, can be added to a PowerShell object, were it gets the property name `<Value>` by default
- Multiple lists can be joined by chaining the join commands
- By default, if the left - and the right object contain the same (unrelated) property the values will be joined in a `PSObject[]`.
- The `-Discern` (alias `-Name) parameter can be used to split the joined (`PSObjext[]`) properties (in this case the` ` property) over multiple properties (aka columnns).

Answer (score 0):

I note that there is already an accepted answer.  This answer provides an alternative to Select-Object for constructing new objects on the fly.  Some people might find it easier to follow. I don't know how this compares with the accepted answer when it comes to speed.

```
$datadir = "."
$filePath = "$dataDir\test.csv"
$out = "$dataDir\test_out.csv" 

$Fname = (Split-Path -Path $filePath -Leaf).Split(".")[0];
$counter = 1

Import-Csv $filePath |
    % {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Employee = $_.Employee
            State = $_.State
            Filename = $Fname
            "Emp#" = $counter++
            }
        } |
    export-csv $out -NoTypeInformation
```

NOTES:

1. I defined $datadir for my own local testing purposes.  It was a free variable in your posted attempt.
2. I used your code, for the most part, anywhere that it makes no difference.
3. The variable $counter is just an ordinary variable.  I initialized it to 1,  and used increment after.  This is just a style choice.
4. % is shorthand for Foreach-Object.
5. Within the loop for each record,  I build a hashtable explicitly,  then cast it as a [PSCustomObject].  This gets piped to Export-Csv.